# CodeIgniter: jQuery autocomplete causing application to sign out

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

Without having kept track of the exact numbers, while using any of the numerous instances of the jQuery autocomplete in an application I've developed, 1 in every 6-7 attempts signs me out of the application.

I only become aware of this when the autocomplete itself reports that it can't find anything for what's been typed into the search field. Sure enough, when I open a new tab and visit the application, I'm signed out.

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and Ion Auth 2 along with jQuery 1.10.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.3, though this bug (if indeed that's what it is) has been persistent over a number of different versions of jQuery.

It's nothing major, but it's happening often enough to be damn annoying.

Anyone else seen this behaviour, and if so, did you fix it?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179243/ionauth-seems-to-be-randomly-logging-me-out

Comment: @Overachiever, I reckon that's what I'm seeing. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll flag as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is pretty common with any type of AJAX request in CodeIgniter 2.x.

Here's a good solution for CI/Ion Auth, that should help keep your login from expiring.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19259607/2566227